# How to help my dyslexic daughter to not get frustrated while reading

Tags: mental-health, pediatrics, parenting, dyslexia-dyslexic

I  recently found out that my 8yo daughter has dyslexia. When I found out, I wasn't surprised. I never considered it, but then suddenly everything made sense.

She writes almost all numbers backwards. She struggles reading words like `the, them, as, in, on etc`. But will read a word she has never seen before like `dinosaur` easily. And she will remember it, and have no problems.

It pains me when I see her get truly frustrated trying to read simple words. The school gave me a coloured binder divider to put over the book but it doesn't seem to help.

I have read that every dyslexic condition can be different. You have to find the best way for you child's brain to learn. But I don't really know what this means with regards to the reading frustration. She has always been a bright girl, and her 2yo sister is even brighter, so I worry this condition is going to stump my daughters mental development if I don't find a way around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Words like them and the are quite similar, which makes things more difficult for a child with dyslexia since they sometimes opt to just analyse part of the word and guess the entire word based on the first part. Such strategies are used to avoid the extensive amount of effort that reading poses on them, though it can increase reading frustration because it makes them fail more.

You provide little information regarding how she actually reads and writes, which would be helpful in order to make a more specific recommendation. Children get frustrated easily when confronted with their difficulties, so one needs to help them mature their emotional skills and understand that that particular difficulty does not reflect their intellect or even self-worth.

When it comes to reading, I would advise you to choose a book that she already knows and have read or been read to her. Then I would do alternate reading or simultaneous reading with her, so that she reads for less periods of time and has the opportunity to listen to a more adequate reading style that can serve as a model. You should be patient and always congratulate her for her progress, even if it is not an actual progress in her reading skills, at least congratulate her effort.

I would also advise you to try to better understand whether her phonological skills need to be stimulated, a Speech and Language Therapist pr Psychologist would be a good resource for information.

You should also read the book https://www.amazon.co.uk/Supporting-Children-Dyslexia-Continuum-Hundreds/dp/0826434169 if you have the opportunity. It offers a great number of strategies that can work for her.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks. I waited to see if any other answers popped up. Over the last year, she _has_ improved and moved up stages in school. When we read the school reading book three or four times, she remembers the sentences so she gets them right in the end. She still gets small words wrong. she doesn't even say a word with the same first letter! i.e. for _"are"_ she will be adamant it is _"we"_ and even sound it out with a _"w"_  It's hard not to get frustrated sometimes. I cover all but the first letter and she gets the word then. ...>

Comment: ...> But i'm always proud, supportive and I always commend her efforts and I think that helps. She will read some sentences first time and quickly too, as if she has no problem, and that always makes me happy. But repetition and support is the key I think.